# How can I coerce arrays to slices inside a match arm?

Tags: arrays, enums, rust, pattern-matching

I have an enum where each variant has an array, but the arrays are different lengths. If I try to `match` on that enum:

```rust
enum EnumArray {
    One([i32; 1]),
    Two([i32; 2]),
}

fn main() {
    let arr = EnumArray::One([1]);
    match arr {
        EnumArray::One(arr) | EnumArray::Two(arr) => use_array_as_slice(&arr),
    }
}

fn use_array_as_slice(arr: &[i32]) {}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:46
  |
8 |     match arr {
  |           --- this expression has type `EnumArray`
9 |         EnumArray::One(arr) | EnumArray::Two(arr) => use_array_as_slice(&arr),
  |                                              ^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 1 element, found one with 2 elements
  |
  = note: expected type `[i32; 1]`
             found type `[i32; 2]`
```

As I understand, I need to coerce `[i32; 1]` and `[i32; 2]` types to `&[i32]` to fix this error. How can I do this inside the `match` arm?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=05e68bca60e3473a14b439797e494ec2)

"Use two `match` arms" is not an answer to this question.

Comment: *"Use two match arms" is not an answer to this question* — Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot; you will need to use two match arms:

```
match arr {
    EnumArray::One(arr) => use_array_as_slice(&arr),
    EnumArray::Two(arr) => use_array_as_slice(&arr),
}
```

Pattern matching is a compile-time concept, coercion is a run-time concept. You cannot "run code" in a pattern.